# Trouble getting two-column sticky-scroller to work

Tags: html, css, sticky

I am creating a cover block that has two columns. The div column on the left has some large print text that scrolls with the page, and the div on the right is a sticky element that should stay pinned to the screen while scrolling within the bounds of the cover container.

The trouble I'm having is that I need to allow the text column to control the height of the cover container so that it will not have big gaps (or overflow into the text below) depending on the display size. To do this, I believe I need to set the position type to relative. But when I do this, the sticky element on the right no longer sticks to the screen, but gets pushed down below the text div on the left.

I feel like there is something really simple I'm missing here. Here's a CodePen example I made to illustrate the simplest test case to observe the problem. If you change the position property inside the `two_column_cover_text` CSS selector from absolute to relative, you'll see the problem there.

https://codepen.io/Jdo300/pen/XWYejJb

There also an odd overlap issue between the sticky and the text column, though that only appears to be happening inside the CodePen example and not on my real site. Any help / insights would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you can achieve what you want with position:fixed, sticky only works if there is an overflow

Comment: @Skin_phil This works, but how do I unfix it from the viewport so that it scrolls away with the parent container once you get to the bottom? Is there a simple CSS way to accomplish this? Is there something I can modify to make the overflow happen? The sticky container is normally longer than the height of the viewport, if that's what you're referring to.

Comment: Try now, went back to sticky, but there are a few hard coded margins for this to work, can’t think of a better way right now but I’ll give it some thought tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#cover_container {

    background:yellow;
    position:relative;
    
    }
#cover_sticky{
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
  width:50%;
  margin-left:50%;
}
#cover_text{
/*should be the same as the image height*/
margin-top:-100px;
  width:50%;
  heigth:fit-content;
}

img{
width:00px;
height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="cover_container" class="sticky_cover_container">

    <!-- Right image sticky-->
    <div id="cover_sticky" class="two_column_cover_sticky">
        <figure id="sticky_figure">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x600.jpeg?text=Figure+Placeholder">
            <figcaption id="sticky_figure_caption" class="wp-element-caption"><a href="http://placeholder.com">Image</a> courtesy of placeholder.com</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>


    <!-- Left text column-->
    <div id="cover_text" class="two_column_cover_text">
                <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</h4>
        <h4>Turpis cursus in hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque sagittis. Adipiscing elit pellentesque habitant morbi. Porta non pulvinar neque laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur libero. Congue eu consequat ac felis donec et odio pellentesque diam. Ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue eget. Pretium vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu. Nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis a. Convallis tellus id interdum velit laoreet id. Sit amet aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies mi eget. Phasellus vestibulum lorem sed risus ultricies tristique nulla aliquet enim. Suspendisse interdum consectetur libero id faucibus. Ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus venenatis.</h4>
    </div>


</div>

<div style="height:600px;background:red;"></div>
```

Hope you get the idea, just play with heights and widths, also removed the mobile section, wasn’t working quite right

Comment: This absolutely fixed my problem! Thank you! It looks like the main thing was changing the order that the two columns were drawn in! I'm not sure why but I didn't need to add the negative margin to the text column once I ported the code back to my website. Thanks again!